Using Docx4j in a Graal native image
The Docx4j guide says on page 5 that:

Programs based on docx4j can be converted to a Graal native image, and run "serverless" on AWS Lambda.

I have attempted to do this but additional configuration of the native image compiler is required to ensure that reflection and access of resource files etc can take place at runtime. My attempts have included updating the configuration to account for each error that I find when running an image but such an approach has consumed a number of hours with no end in sight.
Some assistance in this task is provided by the GraalVM reachability metadata GitHub repo, which provides a template for configuring JAXB (upon which Docx4j depends); however this is far from a complete solution.
Is anyone able to share a configuration to allow Docx4j to work with Graal or otherwise share a path to creating one?

In the end I was able to get my (fairly simple) Docx4j app to work on Graal solely by using the configuration generated by using Graal's tracing agent.
Importantly, I wrote and executed a path through my app with the tracing agent that (I believe) accessed all classes and methods needed by my app at runtime in regular operation.
Using this output configuration, I did not find it necessary to do any additional configuration of reflection or resources.
However, I concluded that I am not going to bundle Docx4j in production in this way since I have, without greater knowledge of how Docx4j works, no confidence that I have covered all possible routes through the app that a user might take, were they to use the app with different kinds of documents. In such an event, Docx4j might try to access resources or classes that were not in my native image owing to them not having been accessed during my tracing build step.
